# (amp) image float right may not grow beyond 100%

Tags: image, amp-html

This is about AMP pages, the problem is that the image does resize beyond the original format, don't know how to fix it.

I like to achieve:

- an image that floats on the right (and the text flows around it)
- occupies maximum 40% of the viewport
- image must shrink below original size if 40% of viewport is smaller than the orignal image size
- image may not grow beyond original size
- the css part should work with all size of images (so no image size specification in the css part)
- if the 40% in a certain viewport is bigger that the orignal size of the image that the div including the image may not growing beyond the original size of the image

Of course no problem with specifying size of image in html code because of AMP.

The code:

```
<style amp-custom>
    .right40 {float:right;max-width:40%}
    amp-img {max-width:100%} 
</style amp-custom>

<div class="right40">
    <amp-img src="picture.png" height="100" width="200" layout="responsive"></amp-img>
</div>
```

I noticed that if no minimum width is specified the image is not shown. So I added a minimum width of 100px, but then the image is fixed at 100px.

```
<style amp-custom>
    .right {min-width:100px;float:right;max-width:40%}
    amp-img {max-width:100%} 
</style amp-custom>
```

Comment: Do you have an HTML page you can give an example of so we can review the code on a live example?